# Modifying Oscar on an pre-existing non-oscar app

Tags: django, django-oscar

I had an app without oscar, I then installed oscar. I updated my main app settings with the credentials of oscar's. When I go to my admin page, I am able to see the products pages and such. I can add the products BUT I see nothing on main page

What I did so far, `pip install django-oscar`, created a new app `django-admin startproject myshop`, modified `settings.py` in my main app per the directions in oscar's. I pointed my `urls.py` to `myshop`.

urls.py

```
from oscar.app import application
admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^partner/', include(application.urls)),
    ...
```

Now I'm expecting `myshop` to be integrated to oscar. I went to my `website.com/myshop` I see my default template. I go to `website.com/myshop/dashboard` same template, no oscar.

Comment: I think it may be related to you using `i18n_patterns`. Try adding the Oscar URL directly to the `urlpatterns` list without wrapping it in `i18n_patterns`.

Comment: @solarissmoke same thing, blank template